# $\lnot (A\iff B)$ is logically equivalent to $A\iff \lnot B$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> Show $\lnot (A\iff B)$ is logically equivalent to $A\iff \lnot B$.

Making some calculations I got this

$$\lnot (A\iff B)=(A\land\lnot B)\lor(B\land\lnot A) \tag{1}$$ and

$$(A\iff \lnot B)=(\lnot A\lor\lnot B)\land(\lnot B\lor\lnot A)\tag{2}$$

I don't know how to make a relation between (1) and (2). I believe there is a trick in the solution.

Could someone lighten my brain?

Comment: Have you tried using truth tables? These will not only show the equivalence, they will also show that your second equation is not correct (but your first is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculations are not correct. Recall that $(A\implies B)=\lnot A\lor  B$.

Now note that for the [distributive law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic),
$$(A\iff \lnot B)=(\lnot A\lor\lnot B)\land(B\lor A)=
(\lnot A\land B)\lor( \lnot A\land  A)\lor (\lnot B\land B)\lor(\lnot B\land A).
$$
Is the above expression equivalent to 
$$\lnot (A\iff B)=(A\land\lnot B)\lor(B\land\lnot A) \quad ?$$

Answer (score 2):

Logically $A\Leftrightarrow B$ means $A$ and $B$ have equal truth values (either both true or both false). If this is not the case, they have different truth values, which then means $A$ and $\neg B$ have the same truth value. This is a consequence of the two-valuedness of classical logic. You can also use a truth table to see this more clearly.

\begin{align}
\begin{array}{cll}
A\Leftrightarrow B & 0 &1\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\qquad
\begin{array}{cll}
A\Leftrightarrow\neg B & 0 &1\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\end{align}

From the above truth tables, the truth value of $\neg(A\Leftrightarrow B)$ is always the same as that of $A\Leftrightarrow\neg B$.

Answer (score 1):

By logic table the first tells $A$ and $B$ have not the same logic values, the second that they have different logic values (so they are equivalent under tertium non datur assumption). I know this is not the searched answer, but was funny and worth to note.